# Memory issues with VGG16 on Tensorflow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to get a VGG16 Keras model with a Tensorflow backend to work in order to classify images for the ['Planet: Understanding the Amazon from Space](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space) competition on Kaggle. Unfortunately, when trying to get the model running I consistently run into memory issues, even when running on AWS's g.2.8 large which has 60 GB of memory.

The traceback of the problem is as follows:

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 1)                 6423041
=================================================================
Total params: 21,137,729.0
Trainable params: 21,137,729.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VGG16_Kg_Kernel.py", line 160, in <module>
        train_datagen.fit(x_train)
      File "/home/ec2-user/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 648, in fit
        x = np.copy(x)
      File "/home/ec2-user/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1497, in copy
        return array(a, order=order, copy=True)
    MemoryError
```

The entire print out can be found here: https://github.com/j-v-k/VGG16/blob/master/error_text.txt

From the print out, the GPU appears to be running, but it might not be running perfectly.

The data contains ~ 100K 11.6 KB images. The code I use to run the model can be found here:https://github.com/j-v-k/VGG16/blob/master/VGG16_Kg_Kernel.py

Please let me know if any more information is needed.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is you're out of GPU memory not RAM.  G2s have 4GB graphics processors and there seems to be an issue with VGG16 and Tensorflow.

I've run the same with a Theano backend and had no issues.  I'd recommend trying that.

Comment: Thanks, ill give that a try